# luaJIT error handling with FFI calls a non-existent method

Tags: lua, ffi, luajit

What I want to avoid is to capture/ignore the exception when FFI calls a non-existent method.

For example, the following code calls the `non_existent_method`. However, `pcall` cannot handle the error.

```lua
local ffi = require "ffi"
local C = ffi.C

ffi.cdef [[
    int non_existent_method(int num);
]]

local ok, ret = pcall(C.non_existent_method, 1)

if not ok then
    return
end
```

I got the following error with OpenResty/lua-nginx-module.

```
lua entry thread aborted: runtime error: dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, awd): symbol not found
```

Comment: The error happens when you index `C` with the key `non_existent_method`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution would be wrapping the `C.non_existent_method` call with a lua function.

For example

```lua
local ok, ret = pcall(function()
    return C.non_existent_method(len)
end)

if not ok then
    ......
end
```

Answer (score 2):

One more apporach would be to call the index metamethod directly:
You might want to wrap that into a function:

```lua
local ffi_mt = getmetatable(ffi.C)
function is_valid_ffi_call(sym)
  return pcall(ffi_mt.__index, ffi.C, sym) 
end
```

example:

```lua
ffi.cdef[[void (*foo)();]]
ffi.cdef[[int puts(const char *);]]

a,func = is_valid_ffi_call("foo")
-- false, "error message: symbol not found or missing declaration, whatever it is"

a,func = is_valid_ffi_call("puts")
-- true, cdata<int ()>: 0x7ff93ad307f0
```